# What are non-zero-sized values in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just read the documentation of the [`std::boxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/index.html) module and [encountered a sentence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout)

> For non-zero-sized values, a Box will use the Global allocator for its allocation

What are non-zero-sized values (in this context and in general)?

Comment: Relevant doc link: [Zero Sized Types (ZSTs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts)

Comment: A better question is what are zero-sized values, because those are the exception. Zero-sized values are types whose values carry no information at run-time. Examples are a struct with no fields or the empty tuple `()` (sometimes also called the unit type). Those types have the run-time size of 0, which means they have to be handled specially in some contexts. For example, it doesn't make sense to allocate them, and a `Vec` of such types will have all elements point to the same address in memory, and so on.

Comment: Also, to explain what that sentence means: allocators in general refuse to allocate 0 bytes, so if you have a type whose size is actually 0 (for instance, `()`), it has to be handled specially. In C++, it won't try very hard and just allocate the minimum size possible instead of 0. Rust is a bit smarter, so it won't allocate *at all* for these types, but this also means there is much more hassle. For this reason, ZST have some special handling rules.

Comment: @BlackBeans In C and C++ the issue doesn't exist to begin with because every type has a size of at least 1. This cause issues in many contexts, too.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes that's what I meant by "it just allocates the minimum size possible".

Comment: @BlackBeans I understood your comment to imply that `malloc(0)` behaves like `malloc(1)`, whereas in fact `malloc(0)` is (in normal circumstances) never called to begin with.

Comment: in addition to user4815162342's comment, the never type (`!`) is also zero-sized. it is implemented as an empty enum (aka [`Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html)), but since it looks so different from any normal type it seems worth mentioning.

Comment: As far as I understood, the ZSTs (zero-sized-types) are types that occupy 0 space in the memory: `()`, `vec![(), (), ()]`, `[]`, `""` (I used [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) to verify their size). And non-zero-sized-types are opposite to ZST that require memory to be stored within a program: `1` (i32), `"Text"` (&str) etc.

Comment: Fun bit of trivia: according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/nevi_me/status/1532772034291310592), the capacity of a `Vec<()>` is always `usize::MAX`.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes my bad it was poorly described. But what you said is what I meant. In my comment, it was not the allocator that is smart about allocating ZST, it's Rust, and, likewise, it's C++ that does not try hard about being smart about it and will just allocate something anyways.

Comment: Note that according to the `malloc` man page: _If `size` is 0, then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`_.

Comment: Note that while `[(), (), ()]` (type: `[(); 3]`) is zero-sized, `vec![(), (), ()]` (type: `Vec<()>` is not: it has a size of 24 (or more generally `3*size_of::<usize>()`), as all `Vec`s do. But it's true that the slice *pointed to* by the `Vec` is zero-sized, and takes up no space on the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-zero-sized types are types that occupy one or more bytes in memory. This is typical of most types, since the point of most data structures is to, well, store data.

[Zero-sized types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts) are types that do not occupy any space in memory, like `()` and `PhantomData`. They have certain uses, but allocators need to handle them specially.